# How to write php unit test to test the stack functionality?

Tags: php, unit-testing, stack

I want to write a unit test for a class handling a stack of positive integers.

There are 4 methods in such class: `push($x), pop(), getSize(), purge()`.

Please help me.

Class looks like :-

```
class Stack {

    private $stack = array();

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function push($data) {
        array_push($this->stack, $data);
    }

    public function pop() {
        return array_pop($this->stack);
    }

    public function getSize() {
        return count($this->stack);
    }

    public function purge($element) {
        unset $this->stack[$element];
    }

}

$s = new Stack();
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the issues you are facing. We wont write the test class for you, so if you have no clue where to start whatsoever, read the phpunit manual.

Comment: @Gordon, I have posted the sample class. What if I dont want to use phpunit? Cant we write simple test cases?

Comment: That `purge` function is dangerous. Note that `unset` will set the element to be null, so if you pop an unset item, you'll get null.

Comment: @Jatin you do not want to use simpletest. its outdated and no one serious about unittesting is using it. phpunit is the defacto standard for unittesting in the php world.

Comment: @Gordon OK Gordon! I will take care of thisw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One test would be

```
$s = new Stack();
$s->push(1);
assertEquals($s->getSize(), 1);
$s->push(2);
assertEquals($s->getSize(), 2);
assertEquals($s->pop(), 2);
assertEquals($s->getSize(), 1);
assertEquals($s->pop(), 1);
assertEquals($s->getSize(), 0);
```

Comment: It seems the one which I was looking for. Let me check